How to convert Time in laravel?
in my laraval service project, I have an Instructor, student and Admin who share different timezones and I have stored them under user->timezone column. The default time zone for this project is 'timezone' => 'UTC'. Generally, the project works by letting the instructors upload questions to set the deadline for when the students have to complete the questions. To retrieve user time zones, I have used $userTimezone = auth()->user()->timezone ?? config('app.timezone'); to convert deadline to user time zone, I used $deadline = Carbon::parse($result->instructor_dead_line)->setTimezone($userTimezone);
The main issue comes in configuring time zones. To set and store the deadline, the instructors use the normal DateTimePicker. If the Instructor is located in a time zone, let's say UTC+5 and sets the deadline for a question as 30/10/2024 6:00pm, the time set is converted to 30/10/2024 11:00pm (5 Hours ahead) upon posting. This requires the Instructor to calculate hours manually before setting the deadline. I was thinking of excluding instructors from time conversion, but several hours will be left unaccounted. How can I resolve this by ensuring the instructor's time is not pushed ahead or back while posting questions, depending on their time zone?
I excluded the Instructor from time zone conversion, but there were several hours unaccounted resulting to an additional field of time remaining for when the question was expected to be answered.

If each student has their own timezone, then let the instructor set the deadline in their timezone and then you convert it to timezone for students.
eg (making up times)

Instructor sets the deadline to 6pm their time.
Student A deadline is 2pm local time
Student B deadline is 10pm local time.

Always store your times in your database in UTC.  No exceptions.  Anything else will drive you nuts.

Good, ChatGPT :D

@WaleedMuaz ? I'm not ChatGPT

@TobyAllen, Storing the time in UTC sounds like a great idea. though I am experiencing issues with converting user time to UTC. computed: {
model: {
get() {
if (this.modelValue) {
const date = new Date(this.modelValue);
return date;
}
return this.modelValue;
},
set(value) {
if (value) {
const localDate = new Date(value);
const utcString = localDate.toISOString();
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", utcString);

